# In the tidyverse, what is the difference between an object of class "tbl" and "tbl_df"?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

When creating a tibble,

```
tbl <- tibble(A=1:5, B=6:10)
```

the result of

```
class(tbl)
```

is

```
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I'm used to seeing this as I use dplyr quite a bit. But when is an object just a "tbl" (and not a "tbl_df") or vice versa? I'd just like to know a bit more about the difference, if any.

Any documentation would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can think of a "tibble" as an interface. If an object can respond to all the tibble actions, then you can think of it as a tibble. R doesn't have strong typing.

So `tbl` is the generic tibble, and `tbl_df` is a specific type of tibble that basically stores it's data in a data.frame.

There are other packages like `dtplyr` that allow you to act like a tibble but store your data in a `data.table`. For example

```
library(dtplyr)
ds <- tbl_dt(mtcars)
class(ds)
# [1] "tbl_dt"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"
```

There's also the `dbplyr` package which allows you to use a SQL database back end. For example

```
library(dplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars, "mtcars",temporary = FALSE)
cars_db <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
class(cars_db)
# [1] "tbl_dbi"  "tbl_sql"  "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
```

So again we see that this thing generally can act as a tibble, but it has other classes that are there so that it can try to do all it's work in the database engine, rather than manipulating the data in R itself.

So there's not really a "difference" between `tbl` and `tbl_df`. The latter just says how the tibble is actually being implemented so the behavior can differ (be more optimized).

For more information, you can check out the [tibble vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html) or the [extending tibble vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/extending.html)